# Can I end a string on a defined character in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am outputting strings to an Excel file and would like to cut off the output when a comma is reached in the string. For example: if the string is "Banana01,2,3,4" is there a way I can cut off at the first comma so it only reads "Banana01" in the Excel file?

Comment: If you only want `Banana01` in the Excel file, why not _only write_ `Banana01` to the file? Are you looking for functionality in Excel to parse `Banana01,2,3,4` as `Banana01` or are you looking for `your_string.split(',')[0]` in python?

Comment: How are you "outputting strings to an Excel file"?

Comment: It is used in a for loop with different strings coming through so I couldn't just write Banana01 but .split(',') may work!

Comment: @ScottHunter I am using xlsxwriter

Comment: "Banana01,2,3,4".split(",")[0] use this

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple function :

```
s="Banana01,2,3,4"

def drop_comma(s):
    split_string = s.split(",", 1)[0]
    return split_string

drop_comma(s)
```

It returns

```
drop_comma(s)
'Banana01'
```

If you have a specific column to treat, you can use the function `df['column X'].apply(drop_comma)`